# Equivalent of win32con.client for Mac?

Tags: python, excel, macos

Python newbie here. Found some code to access an Excel spreadsheet, but it uses **win32com.client**:

`operation=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")`

How would I do this on a Mac?

Thanks!

Comment: This is using windows COM to perform some operations on a spreadsheet. It won't be available on the mac, and you'll have to use some other mechanism. If you're just manipulating excel spreadsheets can use a library like [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but regardless there will be a bit of programming required to change how things work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read the following documentation, then edit, and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

win32com will not work on mac. You can use cross platform libraries. Use either PyUNO or unotools (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unotools).